# Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: native-image-agent

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

after running application using `runagent` and it throws error

````
agent library failed to init: native-image-agent
native-image-agent: Error: com.oracle.svm.core.util.json.JSONParserException: first level of document must be an array of serialization lists```

i am currently using gluon's graalvm-svm-java11-darwin-gluon-22.0.0.2-Final what could be the issue. 


this happens when i run on mac
````

Comment: Can you post the content of your serialization json file under `src/resources/META-INF/native-image`?

Comment: `[
{
  "types":[
  ],
  "lambdaCapturingTypes":[
  ]
}
]
'

Comment: @JoséPereda its just that

Comment: Can you try again but removing that file?

Comment: i have it is created again once i run `runagent`
`
{
  "types":[
  ],
  "lambdaCapturingTypes":[
  ]
}

Comment: Also tried deleting the entire `target` folder. it is recreated once i do `runagent`

Comment: Does `gluonfx:runagent` end successfully? Then remove the serialization file from `src/resources/META-INF/native-image`, don't run `mvn gluonfx:runagent` again, and just try `mvn gluonfx:build`?

Comment: `first level of document must be an array of serialization lists
[Sun Jun 19 13:22:11 WAT 2022][INFO] [SUB] Verify that the configuration matches the schema described in the -H:PrintFlags=+ output for option SerializationConfigurationResources.
[Sun Jun 19 13:22:11 WAT 2022][INFO] [SUB] com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Error parsing serialization configuration in file:/Users/lek-syde/Documents/ATTEND%20APP/testrepo-main/target/classes/META-INF/native-image/serialization-config.json:`

Comment: @JoséPereda what i got after `mvn gluonfx:build`

Comment: Remove the `target` folder and try `mvn gluonfx:build` again? You still have the file there.

Comment: i did that 
[link] https://gist.github.com/lek-syde/f8b34b4b8bcde9433696405ab31e67fc

Comment: @JoséPereda i removed the target
also this worked successfully using graalvm `22.1.0.1-Final` but i had errors on logcat when i ran the app on ios device, so i switch to  `22.0.0.2-Final` since that was what worked for android

Comment: I'm not following... The error still shows you have `target/classes/META-INF/native-image/serialization-config.json`. Remove `target` and remove `src/resources/META-INF/native-image/serialization-config.json`, _don't_ run `runagent` again, then try `gluonfx:build`. You should be able to use plugin 1.0.14 with 22.1.0.1-Final. And don't set `JAVA_HOME` to a different GraalVM version...

Comment: thank! @JoséPereda i was deleting the wrong file all along. deleting just the target it workss now. thank for your patience!

Comment: @JoséPereda please helpp here pleasee
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72678455/gluon-position-service-ios